# Through what mechanism does the voltage rise when brushless motor is decelerated

Tags: control

What is the mechanism behind this effect? Why does the voltage rise proportional to rate of deceleration? Can the voltage go beyond Vsupply + back-emf of the motor? What about currents in the motor during this sudden deceleration phase: can they get out of hand? Is it the current or the voltage that tends to destroy components on the control board during such scenario? Even when components are rated for 2x the supply voltage, it still is very easy to burn something when rapidly decelerating the motor electrically.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a 4-quadrant motor controller.

You are pumping energy (angular kinetic energy stored in the motor and whatever is attached to the shaft \$E = \frac{I \omega^2}{2}\$ where I is the moment of inertia and E is energy)- back into the supply rails.

One solution if there is insufficient storage capacity on the rails (eg. capacitors rather than something like a large battery) is to dump the energy into braking resistors.

Comment: Does this mean that the power generated over the time it takes to stop is roughly equal to the kinetic energy of the moving rig right before decelerating the motor? So am I correct when I view it as being equal to E in joules divided by time it takes to stop to get total P in watts that I need to dissipate? Does it then follow that voltages that the circuit will be exposed to depend on current that is created to get rid of that energy? (using V = P/I).

Comment: Power * time = energy, so yes. The power dissipated is likely much higher at the start of the braking and tails off quickly. What voltage it gets to depends on where that energy is going. If it is going into a capacitor then you can easily calculate the voltage change to increase the energy storage by the kinetic energy, given the capacitance and initial voltage.

Comment: So largers caps means better immunity to voltage increase right?

Comment: The bigger the caps the smaller the voltage increase will be. As the caps age the capacitance decreases.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the mechanism behind this effect?

A motor can also function as a generator, converting kinetic energy into electrical energy.

> Why does the voltage rise proportional to rate of deceleration?

The rate of deceleration is the rate at which you are extracting kinetic energy from the motor and its load. This amount of power is converted into electricity, and assuming that the circuitry attached to the motor is approximately resistive, increased power means increased voltage.

> Can the voltage go beyond Vsupply + back-emf of the motor?

When considered as an "ideal" generator, no, the generated voltage will not be higher than the voltage that was used to get the motor to that speed in the first place.

However, there is also inductance associated with the motor, and the switching associated with commutation can "boost" the generator voltage to much higher levels.

> What about currents in the motor during this sudden deceleration phase: can they get out of hand?

Well, sure! If you put a dead short across the motor, the current will be limited only by the internal resistance of the motor itself. This will be roughly the same order of magnitude as the motor's "stall current".

> Is it the current or the voltage that tends to destroy components on the control board during such scenario?

Either. It depends on the specific control circuit being used.

> Even when components are rated for 2x the supply voltage, it still is very easy to burn something when rapidly decelerating the motor electrically.

Yes. As I said, the controller has to be able to handle the flyback effects associated with the motor's inductance.

It all depends on what you do with the electrical power being produced by the motor. Do you charge a battery or capacitor with it, as in regenerative braking? Can you dump it back into the power grid? Or do you dissipate it in suitably rated components, usually large resistors?

Comment: I have considered and studied all the approaches that you mentioned as means of getting rid of the energy. As means of emergency protection I am considering brake resistor that would go across power rails and be activated automatically through an adc watchdog function when voltage exceeds upper limit (and then obviously it will be disconnected again when the voltage drops).

Comment: Regeneration into a battery would be optional if battery is used. I am however not quite sure how to correctly implement that since I would not want to charge the battery with twice it's rated voltage. As far as capacitors - I'm already using them. I do want to find a reliable and robust way to deal with this extra energy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a boost converter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0XSoS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And this is a H-bridge. Do you see any similarity? In boost topology the current flows through diode D1 when MOSFET is turned off, in H-bridge similarly the current flows through diodes D1 and D4.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR0Tv2.png)</sup>

When there is a need to further accelerate in positive direction, the transistors M2 and M3 have to be switched on. The applied voltage would be greater than back EMF generated, so the motor accelerates.

When decelerating the bridge has to be switching the transistors M1 and M4 -> boost converter.

Comment: How can I calculate the voltage rise? I assume it would be a function of dw/dt angular deceleration? So as Vsup - Vbemf becomes negative the voltage will rise, but by how much? In my circuit I can easily get 3x supply voltage measured on the scope. Maybe I can calculate it knowing the motor inductance and rate of deceleration?